# MySQL show all grants

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, permissions

I have over 100 system and admin users in my db server. Does anyone know how to show their grants by running a single query? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to run a query - just input

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

If you have sufficient privileges, you should get all their privileges.

A bit more fine-grained is the following query

```
mysql> SELECT grantee, table_catalog, table_schema, privilege_type, is_grantable
 FROM schema_privileges;
```

This way, you can do it by user, &c. BTW, you have to run this from the `information_schema`. This information

This [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-grants.html) should also be of use.

Using the `mysql` schema, you can issue the query

```
mysql> SELECT Host, Db, User, Table_name, Column_name, Column_priv FROM columns_
priv;
```

From this [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant-table-structure.html).

Comment: is there a way up to the table and column level?

Comment: Check out my query using the `mysql` schema.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Percona Toolkit](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-tools/percona-toolkit) installed, you can use the [pt-show-grants](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-show-grants.html) to print all MySQL grants.

`pt-show-grants [OPTIONS] [DSN]`

`pt-show-grants`  shows grants (user privileges) from a MySQL server.

Refer to the [Documentation](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-show-grants.html) for available options.